# How can I populate items.add on Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an Android project where I'm using a CardStackView to display data. Currently, I have implemented a method (addList()) to manually populate the CardStackView with hardcoded data. However, I want to enhance the app by automatically fetching and populating the CardStackView with data retrieved from Firebase Realtime Database.

In my ShowcaseActivity class, I've implemented a CardStackLayoutManager along with a custom CardStackAdapter to manage and display the cards in the CardStackView. The addList() method is used to manually add items to the CardStackView by creating instances of ItemModel.

Currently, the addList() method is hardcoded to add sample data to the CardStackView. Here's how it looks:

> java

```
private List<ItemModel> addList() {
    List<ItemModel> items = new ArrayList<>();

    items.add(new ItemModel(R.drawable.pet, "Kobi", "Lablador", "Very Good Boi"));

    return items;
}
```

I aim to automatically populate the CardStackView with data fetched from Firebase instead of manually adding items through the addList() method.

Here's a glimpse of my Firebase Realtime Database structure relevant to this task:

> json

```
"Pets": {
    "JuKuTsG6X5eZn6R1fjQAdNYl8fv2": {
        "petBio": "One of the good boi",
        "petGender": "Male",
        "petImageUrls": ["Image Link"],
        "petName": "Kilua",
        "petType": "Lablador"
    },
    "zL7mNG6xAFW6MMzMa0fbGjXVvLi2": {
        "petBio": "good boi",
        "petGender": "Male",
        "petImageUrls": ["Image Link"],
        "petName": "Polar",
        "petType": "Maltese",
        "petVideoUrl": "Video Link"
    }
}
```

I'm encountering difficulties in understanding how to fetch data from Firebase and integrate it into my CardStackView. Specifically, I'm unsure about the best approach to retrieve the data asynchronously and populate the CardStackView dynamically.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, suggestions, or code examples on how to automatically populate the CardStackView with data retrieved from Firebase in an efficient and scalable manner.

Thank you for your help!

Here is my ShowcaseActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackLayoutManager;
import com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackListener;
import com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView;
import com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.Direction;
import com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.StackFrom;
import com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.SwipeableMethod;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ShowcaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "ShowcaseActivity";
    private CardStackLayoutManager manager;
    private CardStackAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_showcase);

        CardStackView cardStackView = findViewById(R.id.card_stack_view);
        manager = new CardStackLayoutManager(this, new CardStackListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCardDragging(Direction direction, float ratio) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCardDragging: d=" + direction.name() + " ratio=" + ratio);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCardSwiped(Direction direction) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCardSwiped: p=" + manager.getTopPosition() + " d=" + direction);
                if (direction == Direction.Right){
                    Toast.makeText(ShowcaseActivity.this, "Direction Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (direction == Direction.Top){
                    Toast.makeText(ShowcaseActivity.this, "Direction Top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (direction == Direction.Left){
                    Toast.makeText(ShowcaseActivity.this, "Direction Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (direction == Direction.Bottom){
                    Toast.makeText(ShowcaseActivity.this, "Direction Bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // Paginating
                if (manager.getTopPosition() == adapter.getItemCount() - 5){
                    paginate();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCardRewound() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCardRewound: " + manager.getTopPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCardCanceled() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCardRewound: " + manager.getTopPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCardAppeared(View view, int position) {
                TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
                Log.d(TAG, "onCardAppeared: " + position + ", nama: " + tv.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCardDisappeared(View view, int position) {
                TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
                Log.d(TAG, "onCardAppeared: " + position + ", nama: " + tv.getText());
            }
        });
        manager.setStackFrom(StackFrom.None);
        manager.setVisibleCount(3);
        manager.setTranslationInterval(8.0f);
        manager.setScaleInterval(0.95f);
        manager.setSwipeThreshold(0.3f);
        manager.setMaxDegree(20.0f);
        manager.setDirections(Direction.FREEDOM);
        manager.setCanScrollHorizontal(true);
        manager.setSwipeableMethod(SwipeableMethod.Manual);
        manager.setOverlayInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        adapter = new CardStackAdapter(addList());
        cardStackView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        cardStackView.setAdapter(adapter);
        cardStackView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    }

    private void paginate() {
        List<ItemModel> old = adapter.getItems();
        List<ItemModel> baru = new ArrayList<>(addList());
        CardStackCallback callback = new CardStackCallback(old, baru);
        DiffUtil.DiffResult hasil = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(callback);
        adapter.setItems(baru);
        hasil.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter);
    }

    private List<ItemModel> addList() {
        List<ItemModel> items = new ArrayList<>();

        items.add(new ItemModel(R.drawable.pet, "Test", "Lablador", "Very Good Boi"));

        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any calls to Firebase in your code yet. Did you read: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start? Also, specifically for using Firebase Realtime Database on Android, I recommend checking out this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/. While neither is a copy/pasteable example, they should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo